# My sublime text shows 'self' in python methods in a different color even though it is not a reserved keyword. Why?

Tags: python, self

Even though self is not a reserved keyword and just a strong convention it is written in red in my sublime text code. But if I change it to 'this' for example it will get white. Why is that so?

Comment: You said it yourself: it's a strong convention

Comment: The colour highlighting isn't using a Python parser, but is using some [pattern matching](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html). You'd have to ask sublime developers why.

Comment: Because sublime text highlighting work syntactically, not semantically. In other word, the highlighting is done based on keyword, not on what the actual code do.

Comment: @Xiidref But self is not a keyword.

Answer (score -1):

In Python nearly everything is an object that can be referenced by self.
To display this there seems to be a common agreement upon IDE manufacturers to treat this keyword as special.
On the other hand "This" in python is basicly replaced by self because of the object-inherited self-attribute. Therefore "This" in python interpreter is recognized as simple word-/name-tag (like in variable names). But i would strongly advice you not to use it to not confuse yourself and other code readers.